# Run wamp through lan or wan and as root website

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I want to run a localhost php website from some other system. I was able to run the website through the subfolder link as `http://192.168.1.102/website`. But I want it to run as the main site `http://website`.

Is there any way we can achieve this.

I have tried adding following in hosts file but didn't work.
**host**:

```
http://192.168.1.102/website website
```

I also tried to do following:
**host**:

```
192.168.1.102 website
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot e:/wamp/www/website/
    ServerName website
</VirtualHost>
```

Here the DocumentRoot path is the path on other pc.

Comment: http://192.168.1.102/website website is wrong ,

Comment: Are you using wampserver or xampp? If yes, you might have to turn your server online simply by clicking "Put Online"(in wampserver task manager).

Comment: yes, http://192.168.1.102/website didn't worked.

Comment: you need to have   
'192.168.1.102 website' as your host entry

Comment: @JaysonObado By putting it online, how it will access the website folder from other pc? Currently when i type http://website. I can see other computer localhost.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara Yes, I have already added '192.168.1.102 website' as host.

Comment: @Lalit Arora Still not Working

Comment: BTW in the place where you have hosted you need to have host entry as 127.0.0.1 localhost and 127.0.0.1 website

Comment: @LalitArora Yes, but you will have to edit the host of the pc you are accessing from.
in the server pc: 127.0.0.1 website and
in your pc: 192.168.1.102 website

Comment: Okay @LalitArora I have posted my comments as Answer if you have problems in creating a VHOST itself means you can follow this link  http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the system in which you are hosting your website ( I mean the one you are accessing via LAN ) you need to have below host entry

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   website
```

and in the system from where you are accessing this remote system need to have below host entry

```
192.168.1.102 website
```

192.168.1.102 is the ip address of the machine you are accessing , please change it accordingly

Also If you have problems in setting Up VHOST in WAMP you can verify your way with the below link it worked for me I often use to follow this link

[Setting up WAMP server in windows along with virtual HOST](http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp#wamp-step-1)

Comment: I have another query. How database will work for this?
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'website'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @LalitArora Try in local I mean the place where you are hosting the site and see whether you are able to connect or not I think there also you will not be able to connect, As for as I know there is no difference in the database access level .

Comment: @aravind-udayashankara No, its working fine on that computer when accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the apache config for wamp to point its default root to your folder (not the vhosts but the main file) also you'll need to put wamp into online mode so it'll listen on the external interface not just localhost but I believe this is just a * in the config anyway to listen to all not just 127.0.0.1

Comment: You can have Vhosts too how can you say not Vhosts.

Comment: Because wamp is dumb and ignores the vhosts file in certain versions of it always going to the document root in the main apache.conf.  Since he doesn't specify exactly which version of wamp in usage we have to assume worst case and he has the version where vhosts is buggy.

Comment: Wamp is not dumb , user who is using is really DUMB , wamp gives nice access to enable vhosts in apache configuration and you just need to go to config/extra folder and edit vhost file .

Comment: Apart from in versions that have config corruption issues and it ignores the vhost settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the `/etc/hosts` add an entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1     www.localhost
192.168.1.102 website
```